# Dropdown menu overlaps other inputs in the form

Tags: animation, select, dropdown, semantic-ui, animate.css

I'm developing an application using Angular, Semantic-UI and Animate.

I'm creating a form and I'm experiencing problems with dropdown that overlaps other inputs when it is open.

[image]

[image]

Here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/BTCxfk

As you can see removing `animated fadeIn` animation from the class of Semantic-UI `fields` fixes the problem.

Then, what can I do to keep using both Semantic-UI and Animate and having that dropdown menu working with no bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's recommended to use the built-in `fade in` animation (transition) in semantic-ui . this won't cause any bug on the dropdown .So first 
 remove `animated fadeIn` class , then change your code to the  following :

```
export class App {

  constructor() {

    jQuery('.fields')
  .transition('fade in')
;
    setTimeout(() => {
      jQuery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    }, 1000);)
  }
}
```

Note that you can set parameters for your transition like: duration,callback... ,in transition settings:

```
jQuery('.fields')
  .transition({
    animation  : 'fade in',
    duration   : '2s',
    onComplete : function() {
      alert('done');
    }
  })
;
```

For more settings see [Docs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#/settings)

Comment: Beware that `'2s'` is a wrong value. You can set only a type number, such as `200`.

Comment: yeah probably , but that what they said in the docs 
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html#/usage

Comment: that must a little bug , you can use both of them ('2s' or 2000) , here is a working demo : https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/aweWaa?editors=1010